# asp.net help page does not show right routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am using attribute routes to route actions in controllers, but asp.net generate wrong Help Page

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getAll")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult GetCategories(){...}
```

But the result is [image]

Answer (score 0):

Set up your config to use attribute routing.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //the following config sets up your routing mechanism to use attributes
        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```